# Check if string follows format

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-word

Basically I have created an acronym finding macro and it works well except it includes all of our reference numbers. Now unfortunately changing the search parameters won't work as many acronyms include both letters and numbers.

My idea was to compare the string, once found, and if it is in the reference number format e.g.

```
LetterNumberNumberLetterLetterNumberNumberNumberNumber
```

I will simply not include it.

I'm certain there must be a simple way of doing this and me not being able to locate it is a case of not knowing what to search for but anyway thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`LIKE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251796%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
'//LetterNumberNumberLetterLetterNumberNumberNumberNumber

if ucase$("A12BC3456") like "[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" then 
  msgbox "is ref no."
```

Comment: I knew there would be a simple way! thank you very much, problem solved and implemented already :)

Comment: You can replace `[0-9]` with `#`, too, if you'd like to shorten it a bit: `[A-Z]##[A-Z][A-Z]####`